# "the_author_meta('url')" not working inside "href"

Tags: users, user-meta

Here is what I have:

```
$icon =  '<span class="iconfont" '.av_icon_string($post_format).'></span>';

        if(strpos($blog_style, 'multi') !== false)
        {
            $gravatar = "";
            $link = get_post_format_link($post_format);
            if($post_format == 'standard')
            {
                $author_name = apply_filters('avf_author_name', get_the_author_meta('display_name', $post->post_author), $post->post_author);
                $author_email = apply_filters('avf_author_email', get_the_author_meta('email', $post->post_author), $post->post_author);

                $gravatar_alt = esc_html($author_name);
                $gravatar = get_avatar($author_email, '81', "blank", $gravatar_alt);
                $link = get_author_posts_url($post->post_author);
            }


            $blog_meta_output = "<a href='".the_author_meta('url')."' class='post-author-format-type'><span class='rounded-container'>".$gravatar.$icon."</span></a>";
        }
```

The issue is that `the_author_meta('url')` is not printing inside the `href=""` but rather outside of the tag. I'm confused on what's happening here. Below is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the URL is floating in middle of screen and the link itself is the post link. I have changed the URL manually to whatever else and it changes correctly, but adding it like this messes it up, not sure why. Originally of course it was the `$link` but I didn't want to use author archives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`get_the_author_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) instead of `the_author_meta()`.

`the_author_meta()` echos the output, which you don't want to do in this case.

Comment: Thanks, Works now! I had tried get_author_meta....  completely forgetting the "the" in it..  guess i am getting to tired. great help

Comment: You got it! Figured you knew, since you had already used `get_the_author_meta()` in the code above. Please hit the accept button if this solved the issue. It keeps the site clean.